# Blazor & datatables first load results : $(...).DataTable is not a function

Tags: jquery, datatables, blazor

Hello fellow developers,

I'm building an application in Blazor, where I want to use datatables as a way to display tables.

currently when you land on the page for the first time I get a `TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function` error. When I reload (F5/refresh button) the the error is gone and the datatable is shown as expected.

Unfortunalty I have no clue why this is happening and how I solve this. I hope this is where community can help me with.

below you can see how the scripts are loaded in. in the _layout.cshtml.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Charts-->
<script src="vendor/apexcharts.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/chart.min.js"></script>
<!--Dashboard duration calendar-->
<script src="vendor/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/MyEnduranceHubFullCalendar.js"></script>
<script src="/js/MyEnduranceHubDataTables.js"></script>
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.0/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
```

In the code below I call the datatable functionality

```
DataTables = (() => {
return {
    //main function to initiate the module
    init: function (Id, datacolumns, values, dotNetReference) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#' + Id).DataTable({
                data: values,
                columns: [
                    { data: 'id' },
                    { data: 'name' },
                    { data: 'createdBy' }
                ]
            });
        });            
    }
};
})();
```

In the follow code piece below you can see how I call this datatable functionality in the page

```
    [Inject] private IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
    private List<VmTeam> teams = null!;
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        teams = new()
        {
            new VmTeam()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "PCDC BLUE",
                CreatedBy = 1
            },
            new VmTeam()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "PCDC RED",
                CreatedBy = 1
            },
            new VmTeam()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "PCDC YELLOW",
                CreatedBy = 1
            },
             new VmTeam()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "PCDC GREEN",
                CreatedBy = 1
            }
        };
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        var columns = typeof(VmTeam).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name.ToLower());
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("DataTables.init", "datatable",columns,teams, DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));

        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use any blazor grid component instead of datatables?

Comment: Wow, this looks like a right hodgepodge of Blazor and JS - so many JS libraries.   Why are you using datatable and not just building out a grid or table in Blazor?  (I see Dimitris asked the same question while I was typing this!)

Answer (score 1):

A data table is just a collection of row items, each with a number of column items.  It's trivially easy to make your own component to display whatever you want.  Blazor has "row" and "col" definitions by default (from Bootstrap).  You'll have to add additional classes for coloring, borders, etc.  But that will be infinitely easier than whatever you are trying to do right now.

**MyDatatable.razor**

```
@foreach (var row in Table.Rows){
    <MyDataRow Row=row />
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Some2DArrayType Table {get; set;}
}
```

**MyDataRow.razor**

```
<div class="row MyRowClass">
    @foreach (var item in Row.Items){
        <MyDataItem Item=item/>
    }
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public SomeDataRowType Row {get; set;}
}
```

**MyDataItem.razor**

```
<div class="col MyItemClass">
    @Item.Text
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public SomeDataType Item {get; set;}
}
```